# How to hide my hook_menu items from the navigation menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I've got a custom module which I use to define some urls that are used for a json api. I don't want them to show up in the Navigation menu. How do I change my hook_menu configuration so these urls are excluded from the menu?

Here is an example of two of my menu items that I want to hide, and a third one I would like to be visible:

```
$items['mymodule/1/login'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_login',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items['mymodule/1/signup'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_signup',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items['mymodule_bulkupload'] = array(
    'title' => 'Bulk Upload',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymoduleapi_form_bulkupload'),
    'access callback' => 'mymoduleapi_user_is_mymodule_owner',
);
```

I end up getting a bunch of empty items in my Nav menu. I would like to be able to hide those api menu items.

[image]

How do I control that from within hook_menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is MENU_CALLBACK in 'type.

It's for hidden items like API calls that don't want to go in menus

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7

Comment: I tried that and flushed the cache, to make sure it reloaded my hook_menu, but nothing changed in the menu.

Comment: Actually, disabling and re-enabling the module caused them to disappear. I guess that menu isn't re-evaluated during a cache flush. hmm.

Comment: Had the same issue: If you edit the menu, disable the item and then hit "reset" on the menu item, it will disappear too.

Comment: For see the change, is better change the url and change the type key to MENU_CALLBACK, clear cache and again change to the original url, clear cache and then it will work!